# Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid language tag

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, react

In my react app, I'm seeing the following error in Chrome devtools:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid language tag: en-au;q=1
```

The error is also currently visible at the arcgis official site:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-frameworks-react/index.html

This error seems to be related to the underlying dojo.js library that arcgis code is using.

I am not seeing in the arcgis react setup, how to set dojo config for **non-custom** builds.

Custom build docs:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/using-npm/

Using the arcgis react code, how do I pass dojo config?

Screenshot of error (notice no widgets are rendered -- hence the white screen):
[image]

Arcgis official quickstart is throwing same error (see screenshot):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60944160/471249

**tl;dr**

```
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

const options = {
  dojoConfig: {
    async: true,
    locale: 'en-us'
  }
};

loadModules(['esri/map'], options)
  .then(([Map]) => {
    // here you create Map
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle any errors
    console.error(err);
  });
```